# AWK print record posterior to matched record (the post that already exists is about fields, not records)

Tags: variables, unix, awk, pattern-matching, built-in

I have this issue written on the title, I'm trying this:

```
awk '{tamal = match($0,/Pattern/)}{ if (tamal == NULL) ;else print $0;} {if (tamal == NULL) ;else NR=$NR+1;print $0 }' File
```

Well, for some of you, it obviously doesn't work, I have been trying using different ways to modify the NR, but I've been doing it wrong.

What I want is like this:

```
Taco de pollo 
213451346257 
Taco de carne 
4358363693 
Ensalada 
432523498 
El mejor Taco 
234238485
```

and obtain this if the pattern is:

> Taco

:

```
Taco de pollo 
213451346257 
Taco de carne 
4358363693 
El mejor Taco 
234238485
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern match prints the previous line, then the matched line. Then `prev` variable is assigned to the current line - when the following line is parsed `prev` holds the previous line.

```
awk  '/Taco/ {print prev;print $0} {prev=$0}' datafile
```

Comment: is prev a built-in variable?

Answer (score 2):

This `grep` should do:

```
grep -B 1 Taco datafile
```

`-B 1` Before one line.